# My code is returning segmentation fault if file is null and its fine if fine not null?

Tags: c, file

i am trying to copy source file to destination file and if destination file is present interact user or ask user to overwrite and if it is empty then copy it to destination file

My code is returning segmentation fault if file is null and its fine if fine not null? please help me to fix?

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 int main(int argc,char**argv)
{
    char ch,us;
    FILE *fp,*fp1;
    fp1=fopen(argv[2],"r+");// i want to use r+ mode only
    if(fp1!=NULL)
    {
            printf("do u want to overwrite\n");
                    scanf("%c",&us);
            if(us=='y');
            else
                    return;
    }
    fp=fopen(argv[1],"r");      // its good when file is not NULL but
                                 //its segmentation fault when fp1 is empty?
    while((ch=fgetc(fp))!=EOF)
    fputc(ch,fp1);
}
```

Comment: you code looks ugly. look `if(us=='y');`. Also `return 0` at end of main. You need lots of error checking point.

Comment: You may want to check for `argv[2] =! NULL` and `argv[1] != NULL` before using them.

Comment: What are your arguments ?

Comment: Dereferencing a `NULL` pointer is [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), and will most likely lead to crashes. ***Always*** check your pointers.

Comment: You may want to check whether you have enough arguments before running your copy routine. You will screw up if you only have 1 argument, for example.

Comment: Dereferencing NULL pointers WILL lead to crashes. We're not talking about uninitialized variables here.

Comment: @futureelite7 NULL is nothing but empty file and if file is empty i am suppose to copy source file  into it.

Comment: No, if a file pointer is `NULL` it means that `fopen` failed. You simply can't use a pointer if it's `NULL`, other than making it point to something that is not `NULL`.

Comment: On another note, Don't just `return;` from `int main()`. `return 0;`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case `fp1` is NULL at the place where you try to write to it in `while` loop. More over you should truncate the destination file to clean old data, hence reopen with `"w"`.

You should update your code as

```
fp1=fopen(argv[2],"r+");// i want to use r+ mode only
if(fp1!=NULL)
{
        fclose(fp); //close the file
        printf("do u want to overwrite\n");
                scanf("%c",&us);
        if(us=='y');
        else
                return;
}
fp1=fopen(argv[2],"w"); //open with write.
fp=fopen(argv[1],"r");
```

Comment: Thanks i got output but please can u explain if argv[2] is open in r+ mode already above as - fp1=fopen(argv[2],"r+"); while r+ mode is for read and write than again why fp1=fopen(argv[2],"w");?

Comment: @carrercarrer, you would want to overwrite the file. If its `r+` and source file is smaller you will see contents of old file even after copy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using command line arguments, its necessary to check the user input!

```
if(argc != 3){
printf("Usage: ./Exefile Srcfile Destfile\n");
return ;
}
```

I think your `segmentation fault` error due to file may not created or it is not present! If your destination file is not there means it will return `segmentation fault` obviously.

If your destination file is null, try to open it in `"w"`(write) mode, So it will create a file and copy the contents!